# How to use modernizer for validations in IE9

Tags: modernizr

Can you please let me know how to use modernizer for IE9 validations. i have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" required/>

<input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr does not shim anything, it just lets you know if a feature is available. [Here is an article](http://www.sitepoint.com/regressive-enhancement-with-modernizr-and-yepnope/) that goes into setting up input validation with Modernizr.

Effectively, you would do something like

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.geolocation,
  nope : ['validation-polyfill.js']
});
```

You could use something like [formvalidation](https://github.com/chemerisuk/formvalidation.js/) to do the actual shimming